# How to define new functions for plotting in tkz-fct?

Tags: tkz-collection

Is it possible to define new functions in tkz-fct and use them to plot using `\tkzFct`?

Comment: Sorry but my english is not very fine, you want define new functions or new macros ? If you want new mathematic functions, you need to create them like with tikz. In the cvs version of Tikz I create some new functions for arithmetics integers. If you can complete your question, I give you a more complete answer.

Comment: Yes I want new *mathematical* functions

Comment: What kind of functions ?

Answer (score 4):

You can define new functions using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`. For example, the following defines a gaussian function that can be used in TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
      \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-2,0) grid [step=0.5] (2,1);
\draw plot [domain=-2:2,samples=40] (\x,{gauss(\x,0,0.5)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: gaussian function]

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the pgfmanual.   66 Customizing the Mathematical Engine

You can also read the code of pgf . For example, I contribute for pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex and the code is not very complex .