# PGF Math Function to compute cube root

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

When I found that a simple `x^(1.0/3.0)` does not yield a graph in PGFplots for negative values of x, I attempted to define my own function for CubeRoot using `pgfmathdeclarefunction` as below. But, am not able to get them to work.

These are based on [this example for a Gaussian distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/how-to-define-new-functions-for-plotting-in-tkz-fct), and [another one here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11368/bell-curve-gaussian-function-in-tikz-pgf).

This compiles as is, but has a problem if I set `\DomainMin` to a negative value. The `CubeRootB` function does not even compile, and I do not see what the problem with it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\DomainMin}{0.1}
%\newcommand*{\DomainMin}{-2.0} % CubeRootA gives and error if DomainMin < 0

\tikzstyle{MyPlotStyle}=[domain=\DomainMin:2,samples=100,smooth]

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{% From links mentioned in the question
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{CubeRootA}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{%
        ifthenelse(equal(#1,abs(#1)),%
            (#1)^(1.0/3.0),%            #1 >= 0
            -1.0*((abs(#1))^(1.0/3.0))% #1 is negative
        )%
    }%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{CubeRootB}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{%
        \pgfmathifthenelse
            {\pgfmathequal{#1}{\pgfmathabs{#1}}}%
            {exp(ln(#1)/3.0)}%            #1 >= 0
            {-1.0*(exp(ln(abs(#1))/3.0))}% #1 is negative
    }%

    }

% Modified version of CubeRootB per Caramdir's suggestion
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{CubeRootC}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{%
            ifthenelse(
                equal(#1,abs(#1)),%
                exp(ln(#1)/3.0),%            #1 >= 0
                -1.0*(exp(ln(abs(#1))/3.0))% #1 is negative
            )
        }%
    }

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-2,-2) grid [step=0.5] (2,2);
\draw plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,{gauss(\x,0,0.5)});
%
\draw plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,{    CubeRootA(\x)});% Error if DomainMin < 0
%\draw plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,{1.0+CubeRootB(\x)});% Does not compile
\draw plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,{    CubeRootC(\x)});% Error if DomainMin < 0
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: forget the pgfmath stuff and use Lua-code to calculate the values of a cubic root.

Comment: @Herbert: Could you add an answer explaining how to do that?

Comment: @Jake: done ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with CubeRootC is the way pgf/tikz deals with `ifthenelse`. The error message I get shows that when dealing with an `ifthenelse(test,A,B)`, both expressions `A` and `B` are evaluated, then only one is kept. Since both are evaluated, you get an error message. The way my example is set, this problem is avoided. If you want to keep your code, just replace `#1` by  `abs(#1)` in your true clause.

Here is my version of your code. The use of the exponential and logarithm functions is the best approach. The `pow`function does not behave has described in the pgf/tikz manual. I shifted the plots so they don't overlap. Note also the `declare function` method. I find it is easier to read; the problem is that it is local to a `tikzpicture`. The code is

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\inf}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sup}{2}

\tikzstyle{MyPlotStyle}=[domain=\inf:\sup,samples=100,smooth]

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{CubeRootA}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,-1,1)*exp((ln(abs(#1)))/3)}
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{CubeRootB}{1}{%
    %\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,-1,1)*((abs(#1))^(1.0/3.0))}
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,-1,1)*pow(abs(#1),1/3)}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={ CubeRootC(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<0,-1,1)*exp((ln(abs(\t)))/3);}]

\draw [help lines] (-2,-2) grid [step=0.5] (2,2);

\draw[red] plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,{CubeRootA(\x)});
\draw[blue,shift={(0,0.2)}] plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,{CubeRootB(\x)});
\draw[green,shift={(0,-0.2)}] plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,{CubeRootC(\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: cube root]

Comment: The `declare function` that you provided works great. Anyway to do something similar globally so that I can have access it other graphs if needed?

Comment: Also, I see that you encountered the same problems as I did with the `pow` function. I attempted to create a MWE example but for some reason it did not create this incorrect graph when I did that.

Comment: the `declare function` only works locally, you can't use it to define a global function. Too bad, I find the syntax easier to read.

Comment: @Peter Grill: You can use `\tikzset{declare function={ CubeRootC(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<0,-1,1)*exp((ln(abs(\t)))/3);}}` in your preamble to define the function globally.

Comment: @Jake. Thanks for that. The manual only mentioned it does things locally. I never bothered to try it at the global level.

Comment: For me, `\tikzset{declare function={ CubeRootC(\t)=ifthenelse(\t<0,-1,1)*abs(\t)^(1/3);}}` also works (instead of the `exp(ln` construct. This might be because I'm using the CVS version of PGF. Could you try if it works for you as well?

Comment: @Jake. For me it works just as before, with the spike at 0. It's nice to see that pgf/tikz is improving.

Comment: This works great. I really do like the `declare function` syntax, but would prefer to have the same function definition accessible in both TikZ and PGFplots so I guess I will stick to the `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`.

Comment: On a side note, any estimate on when the next revision of pgf/tikz will be released into the TeXLive stream. I am encountering a few issues with some of the function not producing correct results and am thinking of using gnuplot to generate the data, but would prefer not to have to do that...

Answer (score 6):

run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\cubicRoot#1{%
  \directlua{%
    tex.print(#1^(1/3))}}

\begin{document}
\cubicRoot{3}\par
\cubicRoot{-3}

\cubicRoot{3e-30}\par
\cubicRoot{-3e-30}

\cubicRoot{3e30}\par
\cubicRoot{-3e30}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and the code for the complete plot:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\cubicRoot#1{%
  \directlua{%
    tex.print(#1^(1/3))}}
\tikzstyle{MyPlotStyle}=[domain=-2:2,samples=100,smooth]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (-2,-2) grid [step=0.5] (2,2);
\draw[red] plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,\cubicRoot{\x});
\draw[blue,shift={(0,0.2)}] plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,\cubicRoot{\x});
\draw[green,shift={(0,-0.2)}] plot [MyPlotStyle] (\x,\cubicRoot{\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's pleasantly simple!

Comment: This is interesting, but am not familiar with `lualatex`. Am hoping that those things with some functions like `pow` will get fixed soon in TikZ/PGFplots.

Comment: There is no _real_ difference to pdflatex, except the font setting. With lualatex you can use OTF and TrueType fonts as well as Type1 fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround using the fact that `\sqrt[3]{x}` is the inverse function to x^3: A little dirty but works like a charm. Note the domain is actually the range because I've switched the x and y values.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.2,yscale=.5]
\draw[xstep=1, ystep=1, gray, very thin, dotted] (-30,-4) grid (30,4);
\draw[<->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[->] (-30,0) -- (30,0) node[right]{$x$};
\foreach \x in {-25,5,25} \draw(\x,1pt)--(\x,-1pt) node[below=2pt,fill=white]{\begin{tiny}$\x$\end{tiny}};
\foreach \y in {2} \draw(1pt,\y)--(-1pt,\y) node[left=2pt,fill=white]{\begin{tiny}$\y$\end{tiny}};
\draw[domain=-3.1:3.1,<->] plot ({\x^(3)},\x) node[right]{$cubert(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$};
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below=10pt,right=2pt]{(0,0)};
\draw[fill=black] (1,1) circle (2pt) node[left]{(1,1)};
\draw[fill=black] (8,2) circle (2pt) node[below]{(8,2)};
\draw[fill=black] (27,3) circle (2pt) node[below]{(27,3)};
\draw[fill=black] (-1,-1) circle (2pt) node[left]{(-1,-1)};
\draw[fill=black] (-8,-2) circle (2pt) node[below]{(-8,-2)};
\draw[fill=black] (-27,-3) circle (2pt) node[below]{(-27,-3)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\pgfmathifthenelse` inside `\pgfmathparse`, which the math parser does not like. If you use `\pgfmathparse`, then you should use `ifthenelse` like in `CubeRootA` (and the same for `\pgfmathequal` and `\pgfmathabs`).

Comment: Ok, that explains the compile error with `CubeRootB`. I have corrected that and added `CubeRootC` to the MWE. I still can not get either `CubeRootA` or `CubeRootC` to work for negative values of x, which is my real problem. I left `CubeRootB` as is so that others can make sense of your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some simple code for this!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, axis line style={<->}, xmin=-10, xmax=10,ymin=-10, ymax=10, xtick = {-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8}, ytick = {-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8}, samples=200]

\addplot[domain=0:10, thick,->] {x^(1/3)};

\addplot[domain=-10:0, thick,<-] {-(abs(x)^(1/3))};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```