# Cube root function

Tags: tikz-pgf

TikZ seems to graph the cube root function with the code provided - on the positive x-axis. Why isn't TikZ plotting the whole graph?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    domain=-10:10, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:2.5,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-10:10,blue] {x^(1/3))} node[above,pos=0.9]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably because of the mathematical definition of x^{1/3}: `exp(ln(x)/3)`. That's the way it is defined in any pocket calculator.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the information.  How do I get a plot of the cube root function?

Comment: Make `two` plots: one between -10 and -0.0001, say, of `-(-x)^(1/3)`, and one between 0.0001 and 10 of `x^(1/3)`. Not sure how tikz works, but mathematically, you'll have problems at 0, hence the very small but non zero values. However if tikz has a `sign` and an `abs` function (I don't know: personally I do these  things with pstricks), it might be simpler to plot `sgn(x)(abs(x))^(1/3)`between -10 and 10.

Comment: Does [PGF Math Function to compute cube root](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root) solve your problem.

Comment: @Bernard I graphed -(-x)^(1/3) on the interval [-10, -0.0001] and it looks fine.  Thanks.  I graphed (abs(x))^{1/3} on the interval [-10, 10] and only the cube root function on the positive x-axis was plotted.  I thought `abs` was the code for absolute value function.

Comment: @Adelyn/ It seems that it *is* the code , but I've seen this coded as `abs(\x)` (with a backslash for the variable). As I said, I really don't know tikz (I only use tikz-cd, with is a quite different thing from plotting functions. Let me add that you can plot your function in one stroke if you know how to plot parametric curves (it's the curve `x=t³, y=t`), but you'll have to compute the bounds that correspond  to x = –10 and x = 10.

Comment: Another approach would be to compute a Talor's series or use successive approximation.  But Tikz actually uses lookup tables for all the nonlinear math functions, so simply constructing an array of values and importing into LaTeX is ultimately the best approach.