# PGFplot of sqrt x error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to plot the square and cubic root of x using this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, >=stealth]
             
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-5,xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,ymax=5,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis line style=<->,
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue] expression[samples=100]{sqrt{x}} 
                    node[pos=0.65,anchor=south west]{$y=\sqrt{x}$}; 
                    
        \addplot[no marks,red] expression[domain=-pi:pi,samples=100]{sqrt[3]{x}} 
                    node[pos=0.65,anchor=south west]{$y=\sqrt[3]{x}$}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I get the following errors: [image]

I've tried writing \sqrt instead of sqrt but the errors are the same. How can I solve this?

---

Ok so, trying, as suggested by a comment, to try different formulas I got it working with x^(1/2) and x^(1/3)

The problem now is that I get the wrong graph for the cube root.

The code now is:

```
             \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, >=stealth]
             
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-5,xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,ymax=5,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis line style=<->,
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue] expression[domain=0:5,samples=100]{x^(1/2)} 
                    node[pos=0.65,anchor=south west]{$y=\sqrt{x}$}; 
                    
        \addplot[no marks,red] expression[domain=-5:5,samples=100]{x^(1/3)} 
                    node[pos=0.65,anchor=south west]{$y=\sqrt[3]{x}$}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But for the cube root I'm missing the negative branch:[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried with sqrt(x) with the rounded bracket. This is the correct syntax.

Comment: Yes. It didn't work neither but it worked when I used x^(1/2) and x^(1/3). Though for the latter it gives the wrong graph.

Comment: Try with  `sqrt(x)` and `exp(ln(x)/3)` for the square and cubic root. Please, can you put your complete MWE? Just for me there are some mistakes to compile it. See after also this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root

Comment: Using that randabout formula didn't work but once again you made me think of another solution: I simply graphed the function in two pieces: x^(1/3) for x>0 and -(-x)^(1/3) for x<=0

Comment: @downvoter: Reason of downvote please!!

Comment: @C.F.G Don't worry...I have increased to zero.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks a lot. :).

Comment: Please make sure to always post full minimal examples with document class and minimal preamble. That makes it easier to test the code under the same conditions as you are using the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really  know why `TikZ` can't plot correctly but here is a trick: graph of `x^(1/3)` is same as `(x^3,x)` (if I am not mistaken):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, >=stealth]
    
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style=<->,
    ]
    \addplot[red,domain=-5:5,samples=100]({x^(3)},{x})
    node[pos=0.65,anchor=south]{$y=\sqrt[3]{x}$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand where that {x^(3)},{x} comes from, could you please explain?

Comment: `(x,y=x^1/3)=(y^3,y)`.